# Import a package from other project in Ant

Tags: ant

I am new to Ant build and have started some basic stuffs. However now in my java file I have imported a class from a package that is present in another project.And i'm not understanding how to tell this to the `javac` task of Ant. The code is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Hello World Project" default="info">
<target name="info">
  <javac srcdir="C:\Web Services\WebServicesEx\src\com\impl"
         destdir="C:\Web Services">
  </javac>       
</target>
</project>
```

When I try to generate the class file for this Java file, I always get error saying the package does not exist. I know this must be a very simple thing for which I'm not able to find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the output artifacts from the other project into your classpath. See [Javac](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) and [Path-like Structures](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path) from the [Apache Ant User Manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/).

Comment: thanks.. i used <pathelement> tag of ANT and i was able to generate the class file

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it worked! BTW, mark this answer as correct to help others quickly identify the solution.